# Can nouislider connect from the center?

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I've got a slider where I want to judge opinions on part of my website, from -5 (strongly dislike) to +5 (strongly like).

The slider starts at 0 in the center, and it was wondering if there was any way to colour the background of the slider with the `connect` option, but starting in the middle rather than the left or right?

Comment: This currently isn't an option in the library.